# SCIM sdk java issue

Tags: facebook, spring-boot, scim, facebook-workplace

I'm trying to use the `SCIM sdk 1.1` in my `Spring Boot` project again the `facebook workplace api`. So far I created a `UserResource` that I filled with dummy data to test it.

Yet I keep getting an exception when creating the entity, complaining about the email when I already set the email.

Here is my code

```
 // User endpoint for core schema
   final SCIMEndpoint<UserResource> endpoint = scimService.getUserEndpoint();

   UserResource userResource = endpoint.newResource();
   userResource.setActive(true);
   userResource.setDisplayName("test user");
   userResource.setName(new Name("Test User", "User", "", "", "", ""));
   userResource.setUserType("Employee");
   userResource.setPhoneNumbers(Lists.newArrayList(new Entry<String>("bla bla bla", "work", true)));
   userResource.setTitle("Backend developer");
   userResource.setEmails(Lists.newArrayList(new Entry<String>("test@test.com","work", true)));

   UserResource createdResource = endpoint.create(userResource, "");
```

And this is the exception I get:

```
com.unboundid.scim.sdk.SCIMException: Missing Email field: You must provide an email
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out after hours of playing around with it.
The error msg is really misleading, the issue was that I needed to set a username which is the user email and then it just works.
Really bad error msg.

I hope this helps someone :)